# Maven project.build.testSourceDirectory property not working from profile

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to make testing for different folders in a maven project and I need to change the maven's `project.build.testSourceDirectory` property.

I'm using a maven profile for this problem.

My profile looks like this:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sahi_UI_testing</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>sahiTesting</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
            <project.build.testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/org/package1/package2/sahi</project.build.testSourceDirectory>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The `project.build.testSourceDirectory` isn't changed, only remains the default `/home/username/workspace/projectName/core/src/test/java` (I've tested this with `maven-antrun-plugin` and gives that path).

I have multiple pom.xml in the projects, so in the path I have the ../core/.. folder (this is the project's core pom.xml).

The maven-antrun-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <echo>******** Displaying value of property ********</echo>
                    <echo>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</echo>
                    <echo>${maven.test.skip}</echo>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Executing `mvn help:active-profiles -f core/pom.xml -Dtest=JavaClientTest -o -e test -DsahiTesting=true` with `<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>` in `maven-antrun-plugin` this gives me:


**[INFO] Executing tasks

[echo] ******** Displaying value of property ********

[echo] /home/username/workspace/projectName/core/src/test/java

[echo] true**



and with `<maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>` in `maven-antrun-plugin` this gives me:


**[INFO] Executing tasks

[echo] ******** Displaying value of property ********

[echo] /home/username/workspace/projectName/core/src/test/java

[echo] false**

So, we can see that the another variable was changed.

I know that the profile was activated because I used `maven-help-plugin` to identify this.
The `maven-help-plugin` gives me this result:


**The following profiles are active:**

- sahi_UI_testing (source: pom)

I've tried without maven's profile to change the `project.build.testSourceDirectory` property only in the `<build>` tag.

```
...
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/org/package/package2/sahi</testSourceDirectory>
    ...
</build>
```

There the property was changed (but I need to assign more than one value to that property).
I've tried the `maven-surefire-plugin` and doesn't work too.

The question is that why the `project.build.testSourceDirectory` isn't changed when using the profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a not very nice solution to this question but it's a solution. For me it's working and it changes the `testSourceDirectory` variable.

In the `pom.xml` file I've declared an own variable in the `properties` tag initialized with the `testSourceDirectory`'s default value:

```
<project ...>
    ...
    <properties>
        <myTestSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</myTestSourceDirectory>
        ...
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

My profile is:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sahi_UI_testing</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>sahiTesting</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
            <myTestSourceDirectory>src/test/java/org/<package1>/<package2>/sahi</myTestSourceDirectory>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

At the start of `build` tag I've set the `testSourceDirectory` to

```
<project ...>
    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>${myTestSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
        ...
    <build>
    ...
</project>
```

So, when we don't use the profile we have a default value to the `myTestSourceDirectory` variable and when we use a the profile the variable will be changed to the requested testing directory. The variable always exists, and in the `build` tag we change the `testSourceDirectory` property to the desired value.

Answer (score -1):

You can't overwrite the `project` model with properties, Maven doesn't allow that. The only option you have is by specifying the testSourceDirectory in the plugin you want to use (assuming it's available).

Comment: I've understand now that I can't overwrite the `project` model within the properties. I've tried that plugin (`maven-surefire-plugin`) but it isn't worked. I've read on the internet the fact that the plugin's `testSourceDirectory` doesn't worked for other developers too.