# Maven plugin to export junit results

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit

I have a test project, to test a third party code. I have created a few JUnit tests for that, but since my tests are on src/main/java instead of src/tests, I don't think I can use surefire to export my test results.

I need the test results to be exported as xml, for jenkins to read them, but couldn't find a way to do that considering my tests are not on src/tests.

Could I still use surefire for that? Is there any other maven plugin to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be interested in this, I was able to export XML reports adding a listener to JUnitCore, following the example described here:
https://ttddyy.github.io/generate-junit-xml-report-from-junitcore/

If you are interested on doing this, I suggest you take a look at cloudbee's code here: https://github.com/cloudbees/junit-standalone-runner

Here is my TestRunner code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter;
import org.junit.internal.TextListener;
import org.junit.runner.Computer;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

import com.myproject.suites.MainTestSuite;
import com.myproject.util.JUnitResultFormatterAsRunListener;

public class TestRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length <= 0) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Reports dir must be on arg[0]");
    }

    final File reportDir = new File(args[0]);

    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    junit.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
    if (reportDir != null) {
      reportDir.mkdirs();
      junit.addListener(new JUnitResultFormatterAsRunListener(new XMLJUnitResultFormatter()) {
        @Override
        public void testStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
          formatter.setOutput(new FileOutputStream(new File(reportDir, "TEST-" + description.getDisplayName()
            + ".xml")));
          super.testStarted(description);
        }
      });
    }
    junit.run(new Computer(), MainTestSuite.class).getFailureCount();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **testSourceDirectory** tag of the **Maven Surefire Plugin's configuration**  to override the default directory from where Test Classes are chosen.

Please refer below links for more information:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testSourceDirectory

[Maven project.build.testSourceDirectory property not working from profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139509/maven-project-build-testsourcedirectory-property-not-working-from-profile)

Comment: You can also specify `<build><testSourceDirectory>src/main/java</testSourceDirectory></build>` as per https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: My problem is that even if I change the directory in the build to <build><testSourceDirectory>src/main/java</testSourceDirecto‌​ry></build>, I would still have to use "mvn test" to run the tests.
In my case, I produce an executable jar, and the tests are run using "java -jar"

Comment: If that's the case, why not add a main method to your JUnit Test Suite as explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648341/how-to-export-junit-test-suite-as-executable-jar ?

Comment: @Beginner I have a TestRunner class just like this one. I just need that when I run this main method, the test results to be exported to xml, just like surefire would do when I run "mvn test".
This way, Jenkins can read them.

Comment: @AlexanderRumanovsk - See if this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062412/generate-xml-files-used-by-junit-reports